# Using mpl::vector to define boost::variant types

Tags: c++, boost-mpl, boost-variant

I'm using the library `boost::variant` to store a large number of types. As the number of type is growing, I will soon reach the limit of 20 types. In the documentation it seems possible to define the variant using a `mpl::vector`, which allows more than 20 types (up to 50 if I'm correct). I tried to replace my variant definition like this:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

typedef boost::mpl::vector<
    float,
    math::float2,
    math::float3,
    relative_point<1>,
    relative_point<2>,
    relative_point<3>,
    std::string,
    color,
    group,
    dictionnary,
    reference,
    line,
    strip,
    text,
    font
> variant_mpl_vec;

typedef boost::make_variant_over<variant_mpl_vec>::type data_type;

// This is the old definition
/*typedef boost::variant<
    float,
    math::float2,
    math::float3,
    relative_point<1>,
    relative_point<2>,
    relative_point<3>,
    std::string,
    color,
    group,
    dictionnary,
    reference,
    line,
    strip,
    text,
    font
> data_type;*/
```

I'm putting directly my code. Most of types are structures containing very few data.

When compiling, I got a strange:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair< ... and lots more ...
```

Previous variant definition was working fine, so I'm surprised my replacement doesn't work. I'm new to `mpl` so maybe I'm missing something - but can't find what ! Am'I doing well ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though with simplified version,
the code in the question could be compiled on
[ideone](http://ideone.com/Sgx02).
This [document](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.over-sequence)
says:
_due to standard conformance issues in several compilers, `make_variant_over`
is not universally available. On these compilers the library indicates its
lack of support for the syntax via the definition of the preprocessor symbol
`BOOST_VARIANT_NO_TYPE_SEQUENCE_SUPPORT`._
So I'd suggest checking `BOOST_VARIANT_NO_TYPE_SEQUENCE_SUPPORT`'s value.

Comment: Advanced in the problem. It seems this is not a problem due to the definition of the variant, but a generic function taking a variant as input `boost::variant<T0>`. This function sees `T0` as `boost::detail::variant::over_sequence<boost::mpl::vector< ... types ...> >`, can't understand why for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant type definition is correct, the problem was due to a generic function in the program taking an arbitrary variant as parameter. Indeed, `make_variant_over<mpl::vector<T0, T1, ...>>` behaves like `variant<T0, T1, ...>` but is not the same type: it is a `variant<over_sequence<vector<T0, T1, ...>>>` (so T0 corresponds to `over_sequence<vector<T0, T1, ...>>`.